# Автоматическое сохранение состояния лейаута не работает

Tags: android, android-layout

*Предупреждаю: это мой второй день изучения Android; скорей всего вопрос полон невежественности и глубочайшего непонимания сути.*

Как написано в [официальном туториале](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html), по умолчанию система сохраняет состояние каждого `View` при переходе в `Destroyed` и восстанавливает его при возвращении в `Resumed`, для чего всего лишь нужно снабдить каждый `View` уникальным `id`.

И это действительно работает почти со всеми лейаутами, но почему-то даёт сбой на следующем примере.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="false"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:text="btn"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

А именно **не сохраняется текст в `textView`**.

Вот код единственного activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "lol\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Как написано в официальном туториале, по умолчанию система сохраняет состояние каждого View при переходе в Destroyed и восстанавливает его при возвращении в Resumed, для чего всего лишь нужно снабдить каждый View уникальным id.
```

там такого не написано, а написано (а ниже пример) и лучше бы ты учил по русским мануалам, на том же стартандроиде...

```
To save additional data about the activity state, you must override the onSaveInstanceState() callback method. The system calls this method when the user is leaving your activity and passes it the Bundle object that will be saved in the event that your activity is destroyed unexpectedly. If the system must recreate the activity instance later, it passes the same Bundle object to both the onRestoreInstanceState() and onCreate() methods.
```

Comment: именно так

Comment: В приведённом фрагменте речь идёт о сохранении дополнительных данных, таких как значения переменных и пр. Абзацем же выше написано

>By default, the system uses the Bundle instance state to save information about each View object in your activity layout (such as the text value entered into an EditText object). So, if your activity instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of the layout is restored to its previous state with no code required by you.

Comment: тогда еще посмотри жизненный цикл активити...

Comment: а текст в текстВью - это не переменная? которая сеттится туда после клика? вообще не хочу расписывать всю теорию, которой и так полно в нэте, но даже из твоего абзаца можно понять, что данные хранятся в Bundle, но ты их туда не добавляешь...

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с Bundle
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/133-urok-70-onsaveinstancestate-sohranenie-dannyh-activity-pri-povorote-ekrana

Answer (score 0):

Как выяснилось, система, действительно, автоматически сохраняет и восстанавливает состояние лейаутов в дефолтной реализации методов `onSaveInstanceState()` и `onRestoreInstanceState()`, и а вызов первого производится до перехода в состояние Destroyed.

**Но** проблема в том, что вызов `onRestoreInstanceState()`, как и вызов `onStop()`, не гарантируется. Из callback'ов, понижающих состояние приложения, гарантирутеся вызов лишь у `onPause()`, остальные же система может пропускать, сразу убивая приложение при нехватки памяти.